# Removing <tr> from table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have 2 tables and every row has own button for deleting itself :

```
 <table class="table" id="Offers">
       <tr id="row1">
        <td><button type="button" id=1 class="removeOffer">X</button</td>
       </tr>   
 </table>

 <table class="table" id="OffersHistory">
       <tr class="History1">
        <td><button type="button" id=1 class="removeOfferHistory">X</button</td>
      </tr>   
 </table>
```

And two simple JQuery code, for every table , serving for  remove :

```
   $(document).on('click', '.removeOffer', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#row'+button_id).remove();
   });

    $(document).on('click', '.removeOfferHistory', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('.History'+button_id).remove();
    });
```

When i click on "X" button in the first table, it works fine. Row from first table is removed... But when i click on "X" button from second table, it removes row from second and first at the same time. Same row with same number from both tables are removed.. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same `id`.

But, you could simplify your code massively by using the power of jQuery...

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Row</td>
    <td><button>X</button></td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>Second Row</td>
    <td><button>X</button></td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both buttons have an ID of 1, change the ID or call the javascript function within the button

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you need to do this much coding.

You can simply do it by : -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
     $(this).remove(); 
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Remove button</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

    <button class="first" value="button1">button1</button>
    <button class="first" value="button1">button2</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove the row the button is in, not just the button.  Plus, you don't need full HTML for snippets... the editor puts them into the appropriate parts of the page for you